# Creating GitHub access tokens via command line

Tags: macos, shell, github, token

(Mac only for now).
I want to create a shell script that creates a personal GitHub access token for my organization's repositories.

I want that to be created via terminal so that I can automate the onboarding process for an employee. I was wondering if there is a way to create personal tokens using shell script?

I can expect the employee to have an account created and logged in the default browser before the person runs the command.
I am fine if it requires little manual intervention if the link is opened, etc..

Expected:
Repositories to be cloned easily without any hassle and a token is registered.